# ClickOnce Prerequisites in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I am trying to add `Microsoft.Visual.C++.12.0.x86` to a ClickOnce prerequisites in a visual studio 2015 WPF application.

My project was initially created under Visual studio 2013 where under the click once prerequisites button the `Microsoft.Visual.C++.12.0.x86` option was available.

Now that I have upgraded to 2015 I get the message “Prerequisites could not be found for bootstrapping”

I have tried to follow this post ([Where is the VC++ 2012 Runtime Bootstrapper package in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471775/where-is-the-vc-2012-runtime-bootstrapper-package-in-visual-studio-2013)) but I **can’t seem to find the location VS 2015 looks for click once prerequisites**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me after I asked the question (always the way), I could use windows search to look for a package I knew was in VS 2015.

The location for packages for VS 2015 for ClickOnce is
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages**

I then copied the package from the VS 2013 location into the above location and it showed up in VS2015.